# Create a clickable text that I can read on another page with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a loop to print articles (with their title, and their content).
I made the row containing these infos, clickable.
But I need help so when I click on the text, I am redirected on another page which will display the title + the full text.
In conclusion i want to send the data (title and description) on another page that varies depending on the article i clicked on.

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: can you include your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass title and content as arguments, something like this:

```
class ArticlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  const ArticlePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// use title and content
  }
}
```

and navigator:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => const ArticlePage(
      title: 'your title',
      content: 'your content',
    ),
  ),
);
```